# Acumatica - Remove RowSelected Event for Service Order Screen

Tags: acumatica

I would like to override the standard method of the RowSelected event on the Service Orders screen. Specifically, the DocDesc field gets populated when you select a row item for the Labor tab. It will set the TranDesc to the DocDesc and I would like to keep this from happening. I am using Acumatica 6.1 which means that the Service Management Module is not standard in Acumatica during this time. I would like the method that populates this field to not run when the labor line is populated, so the DocDesc field would remain null or blank, this way the user can input their own description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to customize the ServiceOrderEntry graph like any other graph :

```cs
protected virtual void FSServiceOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected bs)
{
    ...
}
```

See https://help.acumatica.com/(W(3))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=4a05d4c2-cd8b-4131-bf3b-d05861de3ae6

You could override the method if it is virtual, like this :

```cs
public delegate void PersistDelegate();
[PXOverride]
public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
{
    ...
    baseMethod();        
    ...
}
```

See https://help.acumatica.com/(W(3))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=635c830e-4617-4d5c-9fa5-035952311aa9

You could also modify the base customization, but since you are not the owner it could get difficult to maintain and track the changes.

Comment: I have already modified the FSServiceOrder_RowSelected, I should say I just don't know how to make this method to stop initiating.

Comment: I ended up just adding a null check on the field to not populate, works perfectly. Thanks!